# compare date fields using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have two `datetime` fields that I'm getting from MySQL, and I need to compare them in PHP. I tried to use `strtotime`, but that just turns it into a number. What function can I use to compare two dates?

Comment: You will need to do a better job of describing what you're looking for as well as show what youv;e tried

Comment: That "number" is a UNIX timestamp, a date represented by seconds since 1970.

Comment: Thanks John Conde, Im still new

Answer (score 2):

PHP has a `date_diff` function that should be helpful for what you're trying to do

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to interpret your request:

```
$mydate = strtotime('2014-03-28');
$week_one = strtotime('2014-03-24');
$week_two = strtotime('2014-03-31');

if( $mydate >= $week_one && $mydate <= $week_two ) {
    //...
}
```

Of course I'm supposing that dates returned from db are strings in 'Y-m-d' format. All different formats should be treated in a different way

### Last but not least

Please, work your question because is too poor to give a correct anwser. SO is a community so Q/A should be helpful for whole community (and internet) not only for who write his own question.

Comment: Will do, I'm still new. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

The number you get after str totime is a timestamp.
You can compare those and transform it back using the date() function

Comment: thanks this helped. I compared in strtotime and then used date() to get what I needed